# How to create a new table inserting a variable into .doc()

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've created a SignIn page that allocates its data on variables using `document.getElementByClassName`.
So I'm trying to create a new document on Firebase using the person's name, stored on a variable (which could bring some problems) using -- .doc(variableHere) -- but I didn't manage to find a way.

```js
let newUserPrimeiroNome = document.getElementsByClassName("primeiroNome");
let newUserSobrenome = document.getElementsByClassName("ultimoNome");
let newUserEmail = document.getElementsByClassName("email");
let newUserPassword = document.getElementsByClassName("senha");

let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", criaNovoUsuario);

function criaNovoUsuario() {
        db.collection("loginsSecretaria").doc(newUserPrimeiroNome) // <- error here
        .add({
            primeiroNome: newUserPrimeiroNome[0].value,
            ultimoNome: newUserSobrenome[0].value,
            email: newUserEmail[0].value,
            senha: newUserPassword[0].value
        }).then(() => {
            console.log("Documento inserido com sucesso");
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Erro ao inserir documento: ", error);
        });
}
```

ps.: I'm sorry if I didn't express myself in very clear way

Comment: I found a solutition to use .doc(`${newUserEmail[0].value}`)

Answer (score 0):

Any variable should work as long as the variable is a string (not an object/array) and doesn't match any of the constraints [documented by Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids). Your issue here was that you're calling `getElementsByClassName` which returns an array of elements. You need the value of the first element, which you can get via `newUserPrimeiroNome[0].value`...

Note, however, that using a *first name* as an ID probably isn't the best approach since it's not likely to be unique. Two users could both have the name *John*, for example, and then you wouldn't have a unique document for each of them... you also probably want to do some data validation before you try to use user-created input as a document ID.